# Code injection in files with 0644 permissions

Tags: xss, injection

My subject says it all - I am clueless as to how a file with permissions 0644 can keep getting iframe injections. None of the posts on this site that I saw quite described what I am experiencing. Every two days or so, an iframe gets injected into some files with 0644 permissions. Just as I think we've got it covered, it happens again.

We have searched the database for stored XSS or SQL Injection attempts, and do not find anything that corresponds to putting an iframe in these files, unless it is heavily obfuscated.

My question is: How do I stop this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what do you mean by "injected"; is the iframe within the file itself or just in the answer by your webserver?

if the former, attacks seem to have access to the server and are able to alter files -> your server is compromised

if the later, the attacker probably installed a kernel-based rootkit that injects this iframe into server-answers -> your server is rooted and compromised

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The injection is actually in the file itself. I open the file, and I see the iframe HTML code inside the file. So, the file itself is edited. So I believe it is #1. So - when you say the server is compromised, does it mean the host has to fix it, or does it mean someone has root access even though we have changed all the passwords several times, and it is just me, another developer and the client who knows these passwords. We have all updated our antivirus scanners, and did complete scans of our computers, so there are no known trojans that could do this from our PCs.

Comment: all i can tell you is: someone is able to alter files on your server, sou you should get someone who's responsible for your servers maintainance and ask him to clean up. fast.

Comment: Thanks - problem not solved yet, but you gave some valid insights. Thanks a lot.